# How to make CLOBAGG function ordering the results?

Tags: oracle11g, aggregate-functions

I have this clobagg function:

```
create or replace type clobagg_type as object(
  text clob,
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx in out clobagg_type
                                         ) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self in out clobagg_type,
                                       value in clob
                                      ) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self in clobagg_type,
                                         returnvalue out clob,
                                         flags in number
                                        ) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out clobagg_type,
                                     ctx2 in clobagg_type
                                    ) return number
);
/
create or replace type body clobagg_type is
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx in out clobagg_type
                                         ) return number is
  begin
    sctx := clobagg_type(null);
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self  in out clobagg_type,
                                       value in     clob
                                      ) return number is
  begin
    self.text := self.text || value;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self in clobagg_type,
                                         returnvalue out clob,
                                         flags in number
                                        ) return number is
  begin
    returnValue := self.text;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out clobagg_type,
                                     ctx2 in clobagg_type
                                    )return number is
  begin
    self.text := self.text || ctx2.text;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
end;
/
create or replace function clobagg(input clob) return clob
  deterministic
  parallel_enable
  aggregate using clobagg_type;
/
```

But the problem is that I get data not in the right order. Can you help me and tell me how do achieve right order? I need clobagg function because listagg and other can return 4000 bytes and in my case it is not enough.

---

Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE GO_PRJ_SACHV7.TEST_STEPS1 (
    test_case_id NUMBER(9,0),
    activity CLOB
);

INSERT INTO GO_PRJ_SACHV7.TEST_STEPS(test_case_id, activity)
  select test_case_id, clobagg(activity1)
  from (
    select 
    testschrit.testfall_id as test_case_id,
    TESTSCHRITT_NR,
    CHR(10) || 'h2.' || TESTSCHRITT_NR || ' ' ||
      CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BEZEICHNUNG AS varchar(800)) || CHR(10) ||
      CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BESCHREIBUNG AS varchar(800)) || CHR(10) ||
      CAST(testschrit.TESTSCHRITT_BESCHREIBUNG AS varchar(800)) ||
      '||AKTIVITÄT_NR' || '||AKTIVITÄT_KÜRZEL' || '||AKTIVITÄT_BESCHREIBUNG' ||
      '||AKTIVITÄT_ERWARTETES_ERGEBNIS||' ||  CHR(10)  ||
      clobagg(
        ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_KÜRZEL || ' |' ||
        aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_BESCHREIBUNG || ' |' ||
        aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_ERWARTETES_ERGEBNIS || ' |' ||  CHR(10)
      ) as activity1
    FROM
      GO_PRJ_SACHV7.TESTFALLBESCHREIBUNG tfb,
      GO_PRJ_SACHV7.TESTSCHRITTE testschrit,
      GO_PRJ_SACHV7.AKTIVITÄTEN aktiv
    WHERE testschrit.testfall_id = tfb.testfall_id(+)
    AND  testschrit.TESTSCHRITT_ID=aktiv.TESTSCHRITT_ID (+)
    Group by 
    testschrit.testfall_id,
    testschrit.testschritt_id,
    testschrit.TESTSCHRITT_NR,
    CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BEZEICHNUNG AS varchar(600)),
    CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BESCHREIBUNG AS varchar(600))
    order by testschrit.testfall_id, TESTSCHRITT_NR
  )
group by test_case_id;
```

I try to add 'activity' column to the table in the right order. For this moment I can add this to the table but with random order. When I am trying order data by aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR I also have to add this field to my group by and this destroy my grouping.

Comment: Can you post us your query? What is your data? What are you getting? What do you expect?

Comment: I try    to add activity column to the  table in the right order. For this moment I can add this to the table but with random order. When I am trying order data by aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR  I Have to also add this field to my group by and this destroy my grouping.  Sorry for many parts of this. If you would liek I can send you all query by e-mail

Comment: You're using `clobagg()` twice in your query; are both producing output in an order you don't like, or just the outer one?

Comment: I need this clobagg() twice and both of them producing output  in an order which I don't like

Comment: If I will use listagg() function I will use                        within group (order by aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR)   and this solve my problem my result always exceeds 4000bytes.... So I cannot use this function

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're missing an order by for the inner aggregate. You need to order *before* aggregating. You do that before the outer aggregate but not the inner one.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an order by for the inner aggregate. You need to order before aggregating. You do that before the outer aggregate but not the inner one.

Comment: Can you explain me where I should do this?